# Why @string/ display on button too

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

This is my main/xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_dialog"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Activity_2"
android:onClick="onClick" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_dialog_2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Activity_3"
android:onClick="onClick" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is string.xml

```
<string name="app_name">mgdf</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="Activity_2">Activity2</string>
<string name="Activity_3">Activity3</string>
```

but its still showing my button ( graphical interface )  `@string/Activity_2` and same for `@string/Activity_3`

Comment: And what does it show at run time? Because the Graphical Editor often shows incorrect values/default values.

Comment: This looks perfectly ok, maybe you have changed something at runtime

Comment: try cleaning the project and re-build it.

Answer (score 0):

Did You tried to rename those strings? To start with lowercase or some more specific name?

Answer (score 0):

Does your `"string.xml"` is really named `"string.xml"`?

I think if so you just have to name it `"strings.xml"` und it should work ;)

Comment: @DerGolem it has to be always `strings.xml`

Comment: @Aniruddha If you read the official documentation (did you?), http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html, you'd know that `The filename is arbitrary. The <string> element's name will be used as the resource ID.`